# TableAdapter query returning null values

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013

I am writing a C# Windows Forms app that communicates with a SQL Server database. There are two tables of interest, `Submission` and `Producer`. On the Submission table adapter, I have a query that executes the following chunk of T-SQL:

```
SELECT S.name, S.effDate, S.dotNumber, P.name
FROM dbo.Submission S, dbo.Producer P
WHERE S.submissionId = @submissionId and S.producerId = P.producerId;
```

When I use a SubmissionTableAdapter to run this query, it returns the first three values fine, but nothing for `P.name`. In fact, it won't return any values from any other tables other than Submission. I have tested the query directly in SQL Server Management Studio and it works just fine, so the data is there and the query is valid. What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really a SQL Connection expert, but wouldn't a submission table adapter trying to return values from Producer table cause some issues? Why not do a join statement?

```
SELECT
    S.Name, S.effDate, S.dotNumber, P.Name
FROM
    dbo.Submission s
JOIN
    dbo.Producer P on P.producerID = S.ProducerID
WHERE
    S.submissionId = @submissionId
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is just a different way of writing the same query.

Comment: it is, but i thought the join might change the dataset and the way sql reads it.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by selecting every field in `Submission`, followed by the fields I wanted from other tables. Example:

```
SELECT S.submissionId, S.name, ..., P.name
FROM dbo.Submission S, dbo.Producer P
```

where the `...` represents the rest of the fields in the `Submission` table.

This is pretty annoying and wasteful, but at least it works.